# SQL query: Using DISTINCT/UNIQUE and SUM() in one statement

Tags: sql, sum, max, distinct, sql-like

**THE PROBLEM**
I have four game servers collecting data. Putting data into a single table. Unfortunately this causes four entries per stat for one player.

**WHAT I WANT**
I want one record and SUM()on certain columns.
I will post a statement that I wrote which doesn't work but you'll get the point of what I would like to accomplish.

```
SELECT DISTINCT( Name ), 
               Max(Level), 
               Class, 
               Sum(Kills), 
               Sum(Deaths), 
               Sum(Points), 
               Sum(TotalTime), 
               Sum(TotalVisits), 
               CharacterID 
FROM   Characters 
WHERE  Name LIKE '$value%' 
        OR CharacterID LIKE '$value' 
ORDER  BY Name ASC;
```

Comment: Duplicate rows is often a sign that there's a problem with your system architecture. You may want to rethink how you're handling the parallel servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me start by saying that duplicate rows in your database is truly less than ideal.  A [fully normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) database makes data much easier to manipulate without having random anomalies pop up.

However, to answer your question, this is simply what dweiss said put into code (using [group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)):

```
SELECT
  name,
  MAX(Level),
  Class,
  SUM(Kills),
  SUM(Deaths),
  SUM(Points),
  SUM(TotalTime),
  SUM(TotalVisits),
  CharacterID
FROM
  Characters
WHERE
  Name LIKE '$value%' OR CharacterID LIKE '$value'
GROUP BY
  name,
  class,
  characterid
ORDER BY
  Name ASC
;
```

I'm assuming name, class, characterID, are all the same for each player, because that's the only way to get those values in there.  Otherwise you'll have to use aggregate functions on them as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'm admittedly stupid at style on StackedOverflow.  OP - Tim is definitely correct here in stating that a normalized db will make things a heck of a lot easier and almost always more optimized.  For the time being, the query Tim wrote should work without flaw, but you might want to read up some more on SQL and probably spend some time drawing out a schema -- always helpful for sure.

Comment: The query works great guys appreciated and thanks for the lessons. The problem I'm facing now is the query works on phpmyadmin but on on the webpage... first time I've ever run into this, any experience would be appreciated.

Comment: @Andrew I'm not certain. It would probably be best if you opened up a new StackOverflow question and explained your issue in full.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using distinct, you could group by your non-aggregated fields (ie name, class, characterid).  This way you can use your aggregates: max, sum, and you will still have your distinct characters!

Comment: Thanks!  Use the query Tim wrote out above, but take his and my comments there into consideration.

Comment: @user1366982 Also, if you found dweiss's answer most helpful, you can give him the accepted answer by clicking the green checkmark.

Comment: Sorry, looking for the green check mark don't see one. I must be blind. Ah the white checkmark lol.